# How do you round numbers so that it affects computation?

Tags: numerics

I'm trying to make a demonstration of how rounding to different numbers of digits affects things but I can't find a way to round numbers to a specified number of digits.

The `Round`function only round to the nearest whole integer, and that is not what I always want. Other ways seems to only change the way the numbers are displayed, not how they are internally stored.

I want to throw away precision, but it seems Mathematica doesn't want to allow me to do this. As an example: I would like to round 3.4647 to just 3.5 or 3.46.

There must be some way to do this, but I can't for the life of me find it.

Comment: `Round[x,a]` [rounds to the nearest multiple of `a`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Round.html)

Comment: @acl Actually, that's not quite true: when `a` is a machine value, then *after* the rounding, the result has to be expressed in double precision binary, causing *further* rounding in the 52nd digit (base 2). Normally nobody would care, but if you're studying the effects of rounding and your investigation takes you into the realm of tiny changes and high precision, this effect could become important.

Comment: @whuber right, that was pasted from the docs. That is, I was pointing out that `Round` does what is being asked for, and this is mentioned at the top of the `Round` doc page.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just specify the nearest multiple in the second argument.

```
Round[123.456, 0.01]
```

> 123.46

Comment: Ah! Now I feel stupid. I did look at that but for some reason I assumed a had to be a whole number.

Comment: There are some problems with `Round`. For example, try `Round[4.811]` and you get 4.8100000000000005, not 4.81 as expected.

Comment: Nice observation. That also occurs with `481/100.` but not with `N[481/100]` so the safer usage is to round to integer like `N[Round[100*4.811]/100]`

Comment: @ChrisDegnen I'm using N@Round[100*4.811,1/100] to solve that. But take care with automatic Map compilation, details [here: 65298](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65298/2266)

Comment: Still have some stupid problems like `Round[4.897, 0.01]=4.9` instead of `4.90`.

Answer (score 9):

Suppose `Round` did not take a second argument as it does.  What to do?

```
myround[n_, a_] := Round[n/a] a

myround[π, 0.001]

myround[π, 1/7]
```

> ```
> 3.142
>
> 22/7
> ```

Comment: Now, suppose `Round` didn't exist. `round[num_] := Sign[num] (1 + Floor[Abs[num] - 0.5])`

Comment: `sign=Boole[# > 0] &`, `floor = IntegerPart[#] + (Sign[#] - 1)/2 &`, `integerPart = ToExpression@First@StringSplit[ToString@#, "."] &`

Comment: Now, if not even `Boole` existed, I would consider going checking out `Maple` or `Matlab`

Answer (score 7):

```
round1[x_, n_] := Ceiling[10^n x]/10^n // N
round2[x_, n_] := Floor[10^n x]/10^n // N
round1[3.4647, 1]
round2[3.4647, 2]
```

> ```
> 3.5
> 3.46
> ```

Comment: (+1) This is a good approach--provided you omit the `// N` at the ends of the functions!  Because the OP wants to study the effects of rounding, they should take advantage of *MMA's* exact arithmetic to do their calculations.  This will demonstrate that the *internal* rounding implicit in the conversion to double-precision floats is not affecting anything.  Also, to really *round*, rather than truncate, you should add 1/2, as in `Ceiling[10^n x + 1/2]/10^n`.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for un upvote. I used `//N` to provide the number wanted by the OP, otherwise it would return a rational number.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is

```
Round1[x_, n_] := With[{m = Round[Log10[Abs[x]]]}, Round[x 10^(n - m)] 10.^(m - n)];

(*m estimates the scale of x, n sets the number precision, Abs function enables negative number.*)

Round1[-3.46473*10^-15, 4] // InputForm
(*-3.465*^-15*)
```