# Strange behavior of MemberQ, Position

Tags: pattern-matching

After importing an array of latitudes and longitudes and trying to find the position of some latitudes I was encountered with an unexpected problem since certain values could not be found for some reason. Position and MemberQ behave the same.

Everything works just fine if converted to strings.

I work with *Mathematica* Version 9.

Example:

```
r = Range[39.7026, 39.703, 0.0001];
r == {39.7026, 39.7027, 39.7028, 39.7029, 39.703}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
MemberQ[r, #] & /@ r
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True, True}
> ```

```
MemberQ[r, #] & /@ {39.7026, 39.7027, 39.7028, 39.7029, 39.703}
```

> ```
> {True, True, False, True, True}
> ```

```
Position[r, #] & /@ r
```

> ```
> {{{1}}, {{2}}, {{3}}, {{4}}, {{5}}}
> ```

```
Position[r, #] & /@ {39.7026, 39.7027, 39.7028, 39.7029, 39.703}
```

> ```
> {{{1}}, {{2}}, {}, {{4}}, {{5}}}
> ```

Out of the 1001 values of the following list rr, this problem is encountered with 17 of them

```
rr = Range[39.69, 39.79, 0.0001];
```

Notice the spacings of 30

Positions:

> ```
> {{92}, {122}, {199}, {229}, {259}, {336}, {366}, {443}, {473},
>  {503}, {580}, {610}, {717}, {747}, {824}, {854}, {884}}
> ```

Values:

> ```
> {39.6891, 39.6921, 39.6998, 39.7028, 39.7058, 39.7135, 39.7165, 39.7242, 39.7272, 
>  39.7302, 39.7379, 39.7409, 39.7516, 39.7546, 39.7623, 39.7653, 39.7683}
> ```

Comment: Your problem arises from the machine precision  approximate reals generated by `Range` sometimes wandering a little too much from the ones you type in by hand.

Comment: All: this is a duplicate of a number of earlier questions.  Please find and appropriate one and mark this for closure.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard duplicate of [(15907)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15907/), but the explanation given in that one is not as complete as here because it references a post on SO for the rationale rather than reiterating it. Could I suggest that they be merged, possibly including the SO answer (or a copy of it)?

Comment: @Oleksandr Thanks for looking.  However I know that's not the best one; there have been others where people detailed the behavior of floating-point binary numbers in decimal representation -- more than once I think.  I'll try to return to search for that later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To paraphrase Oleksandr's comment to this answer: Not all numbers with a finite number of digits in base 10 can be also expressed with a finite number of digits in base 2. Look at this:

```
r // FullForm
(* Out: List[39.7026`,39.7027`,39.702799999999996`,39.7029`,39.702999999999996`] *)
```

and compare it with

```
{39.7026, 39.7027, 39.7028, 39.7029, 39.703} // FullForm
(* Out: List[39.7026`,39.7027`,39.7028`,39.7029`,39.703`] *)
```

`==` returns true because according to the documentation

> Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered
>   equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits
>   (roughly their last two decimal digits). For numbers below machine
>   precision the required tolerance is reduced in proportion to the
>   precision of the numbers.

but since some of these numbers aren't actually equal it can have unexpected results. This is also due to how `Position` etc. works; the other answers complement this answer and provide more detail.

Comment: I guess it is obvious that this is what's happening. Any ideas about the spacings of 30 between the problematic values?

Comment: @zoutoftime Well, some questions remain: Why does `Range` do this? Why does it affect the third element but not the fifth? I noticed you were unsure whether to accept now or not; it wouldn't be wrong at all to wait for a couple of hours to see if someone answers it more authoritatively before accepting this answer (or another potentially better).

Comment: The reason is really no mystery; not all numbers with a finite number of digits in base 10 can be also expressed with a finite number of digits in base 2. If not, then you get a truncated binary fraction, which comes out as a decimal number very close, but not exactly equal, to the desired value.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks, I quoted you in the answer since this is what the answer should have said from the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Position[r, n_ /; n == #] & /@ {39.7026, 39.7027, 39.7028, 39.7029, 39.703}
(* {{{1}}, {{2}}, {{3}}, {{4}}, {{5}}} *)
```

Comment: PS. Thanks for an excellent question. I would have never noticed this issue if it were not brought up on here.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Pickett's answer, you can use [`Round`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round.html) to get closer to the expected behaviour (see also [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7872/5485)):

```
r = Round[Range[39.7026, 39.703, 0.0001], 0.0001]; 
r // InputForm
```

> {39.702600000000004, 39.7027, 39.7028, 39.7029, 39.703}

```
MemberQ[r, #] & /@ {39.7026, 39.7027, 39.7028, 39.7029, 39.703}
```

> {True, True, True, True, True}

I don't know why the first element of `r` isn't completely rounded as I would have expected; perhaps someone else can elucidate on that.