# MemberQ giving false when the answer is true?

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-value

Lets generate a large grid

```
grid=Table[{i,j},{i,0,10,.01},{j,0,10,.01}]
MemberQ[grid,{7.02,.02}]
```

> The above MemberQ gives me False. (even though it must be true because
>   the grid has every pair from (0,0) to (10,10) in increments of (.01)

It also gives me false for **every** ordered pair that starts with 7.02

I have tried wrapping the grid and the ordered pair in `N` function, but it did not solve the problem

I have also tried using a subset of the grid, i.e. `grid[[703]]`

replacing `MemberQ` with `FreeQ` does work though

(even stranger, I started a new kernel and tried the exercise again and now both MemberQ and FreeQ are giving me false for **every** ordered pair... i'll try restarting mathematica I guess.)

Comment: I think you need to flatten your list: MemberQ[Flatten[grid, 1], {7.02, 0.02}] 

However, this doesn't solve the problem, and the result is still False. Surprisingly, MemberQ[Flatten[grid, 1], {7.03, 0.02}] gives True as output..

Comment: possible duplicate: [Strange behavior of MemberQ, Position](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55109/5478)

Comment: Yes, they seem to be the same (or at least similar enough). Sorry about that.

Comment: @Kuba Now I did accidentally what you tried to prevent: Closing this post single-handedly. -.- Anyways, this is clearly a duplicate.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher nothing wrong with that. Especially if that is your area. I wouldn't hesitate with a front end related question.  And, majmun, no worries, it is not always easy to find an answer within existing ones.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use pattern matching with floating point numbers. That is the problem. Look at this:

```
With[{pts = Flatten[grid, 1]},
 Min[Norm /@ (pts - ConstantArray[{7.02, .02}, Most@Dimensions[pts]])]
 ]
```

> 8.88178*10^-16

Better use a (relative) tolerance and a significantly faster method like `Nearest`:

```
pts = Developer`ToPackedArray@Flatten[N@grid, 1];
size = Sqrt[Max[Total[(pts^2), {2}]]];
nf = Nearest[pts -> "Index"];
containedQ[pt_] := Length[nf[pt, {1, size $MachineEpsilon}]] > 0;

containedQ[{7.02, .02}]
```

> True

Comment: Couple questions about your code if you have a moment to answer: 1) nf is a nearest *function* (because you didn't specify a point)? 2) What is the `{1, size $MachineEpsilon}` in containedQ doing? 3)overall, this code is defining a tolerance for how close a point needs to be to be considered the same, and containedQ being true means there is such a point, correct? Sorry about commenting on a closed question/duplcate.

Comment: No problem, this is a site to _ask_ questions. =) At 1) Yes! That's why I called it `nf`. The function is set up so that it returns only the indices of points found. This is a bit more efficient that returning the points themselves.

Comment: At 2) `size $MachineEpsilon` tells `nf` to look up points only in distance at most  `size $MachineEpsilon`. `1` means that at most one point index should be returned. So the return of `nf[pt, {1, size $MachineEpsilon}]` is a list of at exactly one integer if there is a point in `pts` that is closer to `pt` than `size $MachineEpsilon`; otherwise, `nf[pt, {1, size $MachineEpsilon}]` returns the empty list `{}`. So we are left to check whether the `Length` of the output list is greater than `0`. 3) Exactly! =D

Comment: Thats very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment, but not really an answer:

there is something weird going on with MemberQ:

```
grid = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 7.1, .01}, {j, 0, 0.1, .01}], 1];
MemberQ[grid, {7.02, 0.02}]

grid = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 3, 7.1, .01}, {j, 0, 0.1, .01}], 1];
MemberQ[grid, {7.02, 0.02}]

grid = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 3.01, 7.1, .01}, {j, 0, 0.1, .01}], 1];
MemberQ[grid, {7.02, 0.02}]

grid = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 4, 7.1, .01}, {j, 0, 0.1, .01}], 1];
MemberQ[grid, {7.02, 0.02}]

grid = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 7, 7.1, .01}, {j, 0, 0.1, .01}], 1];
MemberQ[grid, {7.02, 0.02}]
```

> False
>
> False
>
> True
>
> True
>
> True

It looks like for values of i starting from 0 up to 3 the code doesn't work, while from 3.01 to 7 it does work...

Rounding to the second decimal point works:

```
grid = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 7.1, .01}, {j, 0, 0.1, .01}], 1];
MemberQ[Round[grid, 0.01], Round[{7.02, 0.02}, 0.01]]
```

> True

I'm tempted to say that this is a bug, let's see what other people thinks..

Comment: Thanks for helping look into this.