# NDSolve refuses to initialise when solving an integro-differential equation with custom pdetoode solver scheme

Tags: differential-equations, physics, integral-equations, finite-difference-method

**Problem Background**

Recently I'm attempting to replicate the result of the following research paper on the [Nonlocal description of Evaporating Drops](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.3491133). The equation of motion of a evaporating, spreading drop is described as

[image]

Where the kernel $K(r,r')$ is defined as such,

[image]

**My current approach**

To deal with the coupled system of integro-differential equations, I've decided to discretise the system with the useful [`pdetoode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/87074) into a massive system of coupled ODEs. By expressing the integral as a sum across spatial coordinates, I can simplify the problem to a coupled ODE problem.

As mentioned by [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/270457/87074), the high order of the differentiation leads to problem with conservation, necessitating numerical calculation of the respective intermediates. The equations are therefore defined as such:

```
(*Defining Variables*)

a = 0.001;(*pseudo hanmaker's constant*)
hf = 0.01;(*precursor film thickness*)
μ = 1;(*viscosity*)
β = 1;(*Evaporation Constant*)

(*Defining Equations*)

With[{h = h[r, t], P = P[r, t], Q = Q[r, t], J = J[r, t]}, 
 EqnP = P == D[h, r, r] + D[h, r]/r + a^2/h^3; 
 EqnQ = Q == 1/3 h^3 r D[P, r]; 
 EqnC = D[h, t] + (μ D[Q, r])/r == -J; 
 EqnJ = J == (β D[Int[r, t], r])/r;]

(*Defining Initial and Boundary Conditions*)

IC = {h[r, t] == 20 E^-(r/20)^2 + hf} /. t -> 0
BC = {{D[h[r, t], r] == 0, D[h[r, t], r, r, r] == 0, D[h[x, t], x] == 0, 
       D[h[x, t], x, x, x] == 0} /. {r -> lb, x -> rb}}
```

The integral, $\int_{0}^{\infty} K(r,r')\frac{\partial}{\partial r'} (\frac{h}{hf})^3 \,dr'$ is completed as such:

1. $\frac{\partial}{\partial r'} (\frac{h}{hf})^3$ is discretised into a list of differences  of $h(r,t)$, and the integrand is integrated via the midpoint rule;
2. For $r'\approx r$, there is an integrable singularity for $K(r,r')$. We approximate $K(r,r')$ as $\frac{r}{\pi}\ln|r'-r|$ and integrate it symbolically to find the integral for this region.

```
(*Discretising the Integral Function*)

lb = 1/100; rb = 50;
difforder = 2;
points = 100;

unitStepExpand = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@# &;
step = (rb - lb)/points;
grid = Array[# &, points, {lb, rb}];

hgrid = h[#][t] & /@ grid;
hdgrid = fdd[Derivative[1], grid, hgrid];

Kernel[r_, i_] := (
   2 r)/π unitStepExpand@
    If[r > i, r (EllipticK[i/r] - EllipticE[i/r]), 
     i (EllipticK[r/i] - EllipticE[r/i])];

IntegratedSingularity[r_, i_] := 
 r/π Sqrt[(r - i)^2] (Log[Sqrt[(r - i)^2]] - 1)

Integrand = 
  D[(hf/h[r, t])^3, r] /. Thread[{D[h[r, t], r], h[r, t]} -> {hdgrid, hgrid}];

Int[r_][t_] := 
  Total@Table[
    unitStepExpand@
     If[Sqrt[(r - lb - (i + 0.5) step)^2] <= 
       3 step, (IntegratedSingularity[r, lb + (i + 1) step] - 
         IntegratedSingularity[r, lb + i step])*0.5 (Integrand[[i]] + 
         Integrand[[i + 1]]), 
      step*Kernel[r, 
        lb + (i + 0.5) step]*0.5 (Integrand[[i]] + 
         Integrand[[i + 1]])], {i, 1, points - 1}];
```

The rest of the system is then discretised as such:

```
(*Discretising the rest of the system*)

ptoofunc = 
  pdetoode[{h[r, t], P[r, t], Q[r, t], J[r, t], Int[r, t]}, t, grid, 
   difforder];
removeredundant = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;

odeadd = Map[ptoofunc, {EqnP, EqnQ, EqnJ}, {2}];
ode = Block[{P, Q, J}, Set @@@ odeadd; ptoofunc@EqnC] // 
   removeredundant;
odIC = ptoofunc@IC;

(*For some weird reason if you apply ptoofunc to a boundary condition at a finite value ie /
D[h[r,t],r]/.r->50==0,it would discretise all values of D[h[r,t],r] prior to 50 (ie /
49,48,47,46...) as 0 as well. I have to manually choose the correct boundary conditions from /
the given list*)

(*Edit: Resolved with fractional lb instead of MachinePrecision*)

With[{sf = 1}, odBC = diffbc[t, sf]@BC // ptoofunc];

(*Solving the System*)
var = h /@ grid;
Monitor[sollst = 
  NDSolveValue[{ode, odIC, odBC}, var, {t, 0, 1}, 
   EvaluationMonitor :> (time = t)], time]
```

**Current Situation**

At the `NDSolveValue` step, however, the code refuses to initialise and the "time" under the `EvaluatioMonitor` does not change into any numbers. Leaving `NDSolveValue` to run on its own eventually causes the computer to lag severely and eventually crash. In fact, `NDSolveValue` does not stop evaluating even if it encountered an error, and refuses to abort after running for a certain amount of time.

Personally, I'm not sure whether this is an issue with computational power, or that there are certain parts of my approach that is erroneous but I am personally unable to see. I would therefore like to ask the following questions:

1. Is my approach to this problem computationally sound?
2. Is there any severe inefficiency in my approach that I can simplify for the problem?
3. Are there any other potential issues with my code?

Thank everyone in advance for any help you could offer!

**Edits**

At the advice of @xzczd, Ive looked through the integration function again and realised that the integral would take on indeterminate values whenever $r=r'$. This is because

$$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{r}{\pi}\ln|r'-r|\,dr'=\frac{r}{\pi}(r-b)(\ln|r-b|-1)-\frac{r}{\pi}(r-a)(\ln|r-a|-1)$$

Notice that whenever $a=r$ or $b=r$, $\ln|a-r|=-\infty$ resulting in the indefinite value as given.

In fact in our case, we don't even have to consider the case of the integrable singularity at all. Since we are taking the trapezoidal rule, $r$ can only take on the values `lb+step*points` while $r'$ can only take on the values `lb+(step+0.5)*points`, so the singularity does not occur in our entire integration. Using purely the trapezoidal rule to integrate $K(r,r')$, and comparing the results to `NIntegrate`:

[image]

The fit is honestly not bad.

The integral function discretisation is now redefined as such:

```
(*Discretising the Integral Function*)

lb = 0.01; rb = 50;
difforder = 2;
points = 100;

unitStepExpand = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@# &;
step = (rb - lb)/points;
grid = Array[# &, points, {lb, rb}];

hgrid = h[#][t] & /@ grid;
hdgrid = fdd[Derivative[1], grid, hgrid];

Kernel[r_, i_] := (
   2 r)/π unitStepExpand@
    If[r > i, r (EllipticK[i/r] - EllipticE[i/r]), 
     i (EllipticK[r/i] - EllipticE[r/i])];

Integrand = 
  D[(hf/h[r, t])^3, r] /. Thread[{D[h[r, t], r], h[r, t]} -> {hdgrid, hgrid}];

Int[r_][t_] := 
  Total@Table[
    step*Kernel[r, 
      lb + (i + 0.5) step]*0.5 (Integrand[[i]] + 
       Integrand[[i + 1]]), {i, 1, points - 1}];
```

However, the computational problem persists. When the full solver is ran, the computer begins lagging severely and eventually crashes completely by switching off.

A cursory check via Task Manager indicates that the memory usage of `NDSolve` reaches nearly 98% to 99% of all available memory prior to the crash, potentially explaining the lagging behaviour of the computer.

**In that case, is there any method for reducing the memory usage of `NDSolve` when computing the expression?** Perhaps is it possible to conduct numerical preprocessing of the equations before plugging them into `NDSolve`, or are there any other possible methods?

Comment: 1. It's not a good idea to create sock puppet in this site. 2. "For some weird reason if you apply ptoofunc to a boundary condition at a finite value ie /
D[h[r,t],r]/.r->50==0,it would discretise all values of D[h[r,t],r] prior to 50 (ie /
49,48,47,46...) as 0 as well." It's because you've used `MachinePrecision` number to define `lb`, which causes error accumulation. Defining `lb` as e.g. `1/100` or `0.01\`16` will fix the problem.

Comment: 1. Apologies! Honestly didn't know that it is bad to post under multiple accounts, will note that in the future! (However, since this question is already posted I'll just leave this here to avoid confusion) 2. Thanks for the advice - I'll try that out!

Comment: You can merge the accounts: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts 3. The `Indeterminate` generated by `Int` is causing problem in `NDSolve\`FiniteDifferenceDerivative`. (Looks like a bug to me. ) You need to properly modify `Int` to avoid generating `Indeterminate` as output of `Int` to circumvent the issue.

Comment: 4. There's a simple mistake in definition of `EqnC`. 5. Since you've used `diffbc`, you should not remove anything from the discretized i.c..

Comment: 4.,5. Thanks and edited!

Comment: The more severe mistake is still there.

Comment: 3. resolved! See under edits :D

Comment: 4. is not resolved.

Comment: Umm Im not exactly sure what you mean by 4. in that case... I thought the error is that I forgot to add the negative sign in front of J[r,t] so I added it in `EqnC` under `(*Defining Equations*)`, is there anything else that I missed?

Comment: `J[r, t]` -> `J`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141371/discussion-between-ned-and-xzczd).

Comment: @FLP, hi, I have a question about the BCs used. If `{r -> lb, x -> rb}` is for the left boundary (close to) $r=0$ and right boundary close to contact line, then the symmetry and smoothness conditions at $r=0$ should be $h_r=0$ and $\lim_{r\to 0} (rh_{rrr})=0$, and the BC at $r\to \infty$ should be $h_r=0$ and $h=h_f$. However, the 2nd BCs at both ends are different from those used in the code. Could you please explain something about the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from those simple mistakes already corrected in the question, there're 2 issues worth elaborating a bit, so let me write an answer.

### 1

> For some weird reason if you apply `ptoofunc` to a boundary condition at a finite value ie `D[h[r, t] ,r] /. r->50 == 0`,it would discretise all values of `D[h[r,t],r]` prior to `50` (ie `49`, `48`, `47`, `46`...) as `0` as well. I have to manually choose the correct boundary conditions from the given list.
>
> Edit: Resolved with fractional `lb`  instead of `MachinePrecision`.

This is because `pdetoode` internally uses `PossibleZeroQ` to detect whether an equation lies on the boundary of the computational domain, but:

```
With[{lb = 0.01, rb = 50, points = 100}, 
 Array[# &, points, {lb, rb}][[-1]] - rb]
(* -7.10543*10^-15 *)
% // PossibleZeroQ
(* False *)
```

As we can see, the numeric error caused by `MachinePrecision` number is so large that `PossibleZeroQ` doesn't *think* the 2 numbers equal. Actually this is a common problem when using `MachinePrecision` number for indexing, you may check the following posts for more info:

[Strange behavior when defining a symbol/function pointwise](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85059/1871)

[Strange behavior of MemberQ, Position](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55109/1871)

[Position function not always returning an answer even with no apparent problems](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15907/1871)

[Can Someone Please Explain Internal`$SameQTolerance?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86815/1871)

So, by changing definition of `lb` to `lb = 1/100` or `` lb = 0.01`16 ``, and adding `Method -> {EquationSimplification -> Solve}` or `Method -> {EquationSimplification -> Residual}` or `SolveDelayed -> True` or `Method -> {EquationSimplification -> MassMatrix}` to `NDSolveValue`, the equation system will be solved without difficulty:

```
showStatus[status_]:=LinkWrite[$ParentLink,
  SetNotebookStatusLine[
    FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[],ToString[status]]];
clearStatus[]:=showStatus[""];
clearStatus[]
jianshi[t_]:=EvaluationMonitor:>showStatus["t = "<>ToString[CForm[t]]]

tend = 200;

sollst = 
   NDSolveValue[{ode, odIC, odBC}, var, {t, 0, tend}, jianshi[t], 
    Method -> {EquationSimplification -> MassMatrix}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {4.63116, Null} *)

solfunc = rebuild[sollst, grid];

Manipulate[
 Plot[solfunc[t, r], {r, lb, rb}, PlotRange -> {0, 20}], {t, 0, tend}]
```

[image]

### 2

The other issue, though already circumvented by the code in **Edits**, deserves to be mentioned in an answer so it can be easily searched because it's caused by a surprsing and long-standing bug of `` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative ``.

As mentioned above, the original `Int` sometimes give `Indeterminate` as the output, but:

```
grid = Range@6/10;
values = 0.1 ReplacePart[h /@ grid, {1} -> Indeterminate];
NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, grid, values]
```

[image]

As we can see, when `Indeterminate` involves in, `` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative `` arbitrarily changes the precision of `values`, including the those inside `h`. What's more surprising:

```
grid = Range@6/10;
values = 0.1 ReplacePart[h /@ grid, {1} -> Indeterminate];
code := NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[0, grid, values]
code
(* Start a new cell here. *)
code
```

[image]

Cell division influences the output! These behaviors definitely look like bugs. Already reported to WRI.

Comment: already read [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269770/error-in-attempting-moving-boundary-fluid-system/269796#269796) you suggested, I tried a piecewice IC, `IC= {h[r, t] == If[r >= lb && r <= 1, 3/5 (1 - r^2) + hf, hf]} /. t -> 0`, with an additional modification `odIC = ptoofunc@unitStepExpand@IC;` `NDSolveValue` gives an error <The number of constraints (198) (ics) is not equal to the total differential order of the system plus the number of discrete variables (100)>. (to continue)

Comment: @jsxs Check carefully about how I use `unitStepExpand`. If you still feel confused, observe the output of `PiecewiseExpand@IC` and think about what trouble will arise then.

Comment: Oops, I should have extracted the i.c. in the form of an `If` function with `IC[[1, 2]]`. I have modified the error, but when executing `odIC = ptoofunc@unitStepExpand@IC[[1, 2]]`, i got another error >"Part 1 of {} does not exist". I have also checked `unitStepExpand@IC[[1, 2]]`, which looks correct. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @jsxs …It should be `IC= {h[r, t] == unitStepExpand@If[r >= lb && r <= 1, 3/5 (1 - r^2) + hf, hf]} /. t -> 0`.

Comment: @jsxs by the way if you are still interested in this simulation I think the original code has some additional problems as well that was detected later on... Didn't really include it into the edits (the post is already long enough) but may post another answer in the near future to include all necessary edits.

Comment: @FLP, hi, one of the problems at least that I can think of is that an adaptive mesh might need to be used in order to refine the resolution in the region with high evaporation fluxes. Is that so?

Comment: Hi@xzczd, with `hdgrid = fdd[Derivative[1], grid, hgrid]` in the problem, we actually obtained the 1st derivative formulas on the `gird` for the function `h` with 4th-order accuracy, which is the default of `NDSolveFiniteDifferenceDerivative`, even our have assigned `difforder = 2` in the previous code. I am wondering if this would cause any problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @lxy sorry for late reply! My observations are that the code can solve quickly and stably without adaptive meshing, but you can implement it with no numerical instability problems. So if you are interested in higher resolution evaporative fluxes can very much implement an adaptive mesh.