# Difficulty in solving a differential equation with custom solver for a different initial condition

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-difference-method

This is a follow-up question to [this previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277424/ndsolve-refuses-to-initialise-when-solving-an-integro-differential-equation-with/277472?noredirect=1#comment705836_277472) by @FLP, in which an interesting system of equations was solved with the useful [pdetoode](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation/127997#127997) developed by @xzczd. I have tried to solve this problem with a different initial condition (IC). And I appreciated the help and effort from @xzczd and @FLP. The following code is a combination of the original post and the answer. Due to the symmetry, the differential equation for `h[r,t]` is to be solved from $r=0$ to a sufficiently large value $r>>1$. Here, the left bound of $r$ is taken as a small non-zero value due to some numerical reason, and the right bound is taken as $50$.

**My question:**

In the original post, a system about $h[r,t]$ was solved with an IC of the exponential function `IC = {h[r, t] == 20 E^-(r/20)^2 + hf} /. t -> 0;`. For some weird reason **if you change the amplitude of the IC, say, `IC = {h[r, t] == 10 E^-(r/10)^2 + hf} /. t -> 0;`, it would stuck at a small time (relative to a given `Tend`) and return an error: step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.**

**I also tried a parabolic IC defined by `If`:**

```
IC = {h[r, t] == unitStepExpand@If[r >= lb && r < 1, 3/5*(1 - r^2) + hf, hf]} /. t -> 0
```

**but the error of a singularity remained.** Noted that in this case `PiecewiseExpand` transforms `If[...]` to an equivalent `Piecewise[...]`; then `SimplifyPWToUnitStep` transforms `Piecewise[...]` to an equivalent combination of `UnitStep[...]`. This is a necessary transformation since `pdetoode` assumes the functions in the equations, ICs, and BCs are all `Listable`.

For the piecewise IC, I guess the issue may be caused by the discontinuous derivative at $r=1$. But **I cannot understand why the code fails with the IC only changed in its amplitude**: `h[r, t] == 10 E^-(r/10)^2 + hf`.

An even more strange issue is that if I change the side of the domain with, say `rb=100`, a singularity occurs again.

**The code:**

The code for `pdetoode` neglected here, please find in the abovementioned link. Here, `Int[r,t]` is an integral function, defined as
$$Int(r,t)=\int_0^\infty K(r, r^\prime)\frac{\partial}{\partial r^\prime }\left(\frac{h_f}{h} \right)^3 \mathrm{d}r^\prime, $$
where $K(r,r^\prime)=\frac{2}{\pi}r[\mathbf{K}(r^\prime/r)-\mathbf{E}(r^\prime/r)]$ for $r^\prime<r$

or $K(r,r^\prime)=\frac{2}{\pi}r^\prime[\mathbf{K}(r/r^\prime)-\mathbf{E}(r/r^\prime)]$ for $r^\prime>r$, in which $\mathbf{K}$ and $\mathbf{E}$ are the complete elliptic integrals.

In order to avoid the singularity of $K(r,r^\prime)$ at $r=r^\prime$,
$r$ takes the values at the grid point `lb+i*step` and $r^\prime$ takes the values at the staggered grid `lb+(i+0.5)*step`.

```
(*constants*)
a = 0.001; hf = 0.01; \[Mu] = 1; \[Beta] = 1;
(*Equations*)
With[{h = h[r, t], P = P[r, t], Q = Q[r, t], J = J[r, t]},
EqnP = P == D[h, r, r] + D[h, r]/r + a^2/h^3;
EqnQ = Q == 1/3*h^3*r*D[P, r];
EqnC = D[h, t] + (\[Mu] D[Q, r])/r == -J;
EqnJ = J == (\[Beta] D[Int[r, t], r])/r;]

(*Computation Domain*)
lb = 1/100; rb = 50;

(*unitStepExpand is a function that transforms If[\[Ellipsis]] to mathematically equivalent combination of UnitStep[\[Ellipsis]], useful in the computation of the following integral*)
unitStepExpand = Simplify`PWToUnitStep[PiecewiseExpand[#]] &;

(*initial and boundary conditions*)
IC = {h[r, t] == 20 E^-(r/20)^2 + hf} /. t -> 0;
(*IC = {h[r, t] == 10 E^-(r/10)^2 + hf} /. t -> 0;*)
(*IC = {h[r, t] == unitStepExpand@If[r >= lb && r < 1, 3/5*(1 - r^2) + hf, hf]} /. t -> 0;*)
BC = {{D[h[r, t], r] == 0, D[h[r, t], r, r, r] == 0, D[h[x, t], x] == 0, D[h[x, t], x, x, x] == 0} /. {r -> lb, x -> rb}};

(*Discretization setting*)
difforder = 2;
points = 200;
grid = Array[# &, points, {lb, rb}];

hgrid = Map[h[#][t] &, grid];
hdgrid = fdd[Derivative[1], grid, hgrid];

(*the Integral Function*)
Kernel[r_, i_] := (2*r)/\[Pi]*unitStepExpand@If[r > i, r (EllipticK[i/r] - EllipticE[i/r]), i (EllipticK[r/i] - EllipticE[r/i])];

Integrand = D[(hf/h[r, t])^3, r] /.Thread[{D[h[r, t], r], h[r, t]} -> {hdgrid, hgrid}];
step = (rb - lb)/points;
Int[r_][t_] := Total@Table[step*Kernel[r, lb + (i + 0.5)*step]*0.5 (Integrand[[i]] + Integrand[[i + 1]]), {i, 1, points - 1}];

(*Discretising the rest of the system*)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[{h[r, t], P[r, t], Q[r, t], J[r, t], Int[r, t]}, t, grid, difforder];
removeredundant = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;

odeadd = Map[ptoofunc, {EqnP, EqnQ, EqnJ}, {2}];
ode = Block[{P, Q, J}, Set @@@ odeadd; ptoofunc@EqnC] // removeredundant;
odIC = ptoofunc@IC;

With[{sf = 1}, odBC = diffbc[t, sf]@BC // ptoofunc];

(*Solving the System*)
var = Map[h, grid];

showStatus[status_] := LinkWrite[$ParentLink,SetNotebookStatusLine[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[],ToString[status]]];
clearStatus[] := showStatus[""];
clearStatus[]
monitor[t_] := EvaluationMonitor :> showStatus["t = " <> ToString[CForm[t]]]

Tend = 200;

sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odIC, odBC}, var, {t, 0, Tend}, monitor[t], Method -> {EquationSimplification -> MassMatrix}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*postprocess*)
solfunc = rebuild[sollst, grid];

Manipulate[Plot[solfunc[t, r], {r, lb, rb}, PlotRange ->All], {t, 0, Tend}]
```

**Some notes:**

1. This code works well with the original IC, but when you change the amplitude of the IC, say, from $20$ to $10$, a singularity will be encountered. Increasing the point number and order of FD has little improvement.
2. I am wondering if a nonuniform mesh (or adaptive mesh) could be implemented in the framework of `pdetoode` such that a refined resolution is bunched towards the region where the change of slope of `h[r,t]` is large based on physical reason?
3. As mentioned by @FLP, the original code has some additional problems as well. I'm not sure if the treatment of IC will be one of the potential issues. So I post this question here to draw attention.

Please give me some suggestions. Thank you in advance!

**Update:**

1. With the suggestion of xzczd, the code can run with `IC = {h[r, t] == 10 E^-(r/20)^2 + hf} /. t -> 0;`, which only changes in its amplitude, up to T=502 approximately, and then singularity occurs at the radius position of the blob, where the slope changes most rapidly.
2. By changing the width of the initial blob, I found smaller the initial width earlier the singularity occurs. For example, using `IC = {h[r, t] == unitStepExpand@If[r >= lb && r < 1, 3/5*(1 - r^2) + hf, hf]} /. t -> 0`, the singularity occurs at t=0.000024 approximately. Increasing `points` improves things a little.

Comment: Is this model taken from the paper "Nonlocal description of evaporating drops"?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, yes exactly, but the current method is not exactly the same.

Comment: This problem can be solved with using Navier-Stocks and FEM as mentioned in my answer on https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509623/how-to-determine-adhesive-forces-between-fluid-and-a-surface/512014#512014

Comment: @Alex Troune, it is a promising approach but may require more computation cost than the model. Please elaborate. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Actually it could be much faster to solve linear equation $\nabla^2 c=0$ with appropriate boundary conditions on the moving border and at infinity then nonlinear integrodifferential equation.

Comment: @AlexTrounev yes, I could be faster to solve the original two-phase system of Laplace and NS equations. Well, using the simplified model and the current code, we can also obtain a decent solution in a short time. Could you just test the current code?

Comment: I have solution up to 17.1 s for `IC = {h[r, t] == 10 E^-(r/10)^2 + hf} /. t -> 0;`. Is it small time what are you talking about? The message `step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected`  means that there is singularity formed around `r=R`, where R is the radius of droplet. It looks like model should be updated for this case.

Comment: Yes, this singularity occurs at about 17 near the radius position for that i.c. However, no b.c. is imposed at the radius of the drop. The singularity may arise from the integral, which accounts for evaporating flux. The flux is highest at the radius position. We could apply a Dirichlet b.c. `h[x, t] == hf` at the right end of the domain according to the physics instead. The model has been scaled properly, see eq (31) and (32) of that article. I guess the domain size and the initial profile might be related in the current code since changing the domain size gives rise to a similar error.

Answer (score 1):

If "the IC only changed in its amplitude", changing `sf = 1` to `sf = 10` resolves the problem.

Comment: Is it answer or comment?

Comment: @xzczd, good to see you. I tried `sf=10` with i.c. `IC = {h[r, t] == 10*E^-(r/10)^2 + hf} /. t -> 0` or `IC = {h[r, t] == unitStepExpand@If[r >= lb && r < 1, 3/5*(1 - r^2) + hf, hf]} /. t -> 0`. The singularity issue remains in each case. With a larger `sf`, are you trying to resolve a problem of inconsistent i.c. and b.c.s?

Comment: @xzczd, what did you mean by _period_ in the answer?

Comment: @Alex An answer of course, if "the IC only changed in its amplitude".

Comment: @lxy Again, you've made careless mistake when writing the question, `10*E^-(r/10)^2 + hf` is not an "IC only changed in its amplitude", [period](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-people-say-period-after-the-end-of-a-sentence-to-stress-upon-its-importance).

Comment: @xzczd, sorry..., in my mind, I used `amplitude` to refer to the _width_ and _height_ of the drop together. Actually, I do want to change the _width_ of the initial profile. This is exactly why I also tried the parabolic IC for a drop radius of `r=1`. Sorry for any confusion caused.

Comment: @xzczd, please have a look at my update when you have time. Thank you very much!

Comment: @xzczd, I use `Plot[Evaluate[1/r*D[Total@Table[step*Kernel[r, lb + (i + 1/2)*step]*1/2*(Integrand[[i]] + Integrand[[i + 1]]), {i, 1, points - 1}], r]/. h -> solfunc[10, r]], {r, lb, rb}, PlotRange -> {{0, rb}, All}]` to plot `J` at t=10, it gives just an empty figure. Could help the plotting for function `J`?

Comment: @lxy No. Think about the following: why does `Plot[h[lb][t] /. h -> solfunc[10, r] // Evaluate, {r, lb, rb}]` give just an empty figure?

Comment: @xzczd, for your example, I think it is because 1. the spatial position in the plotting function `h[lb][t]` was fixed; 2. the time variable in `h[lb][t]` should be assigned. But the presence of `lb` in my plotting function arises from the integral `Int[r_][t_]` and r-position is not fixed. I tried `Plot[Evaluate[1/r*D[Total@Table[step*Kernel[r, lb + (i + 1/2)*step]*1/2*(Integrand[[i]] +Integrand[[i + 1]]), {i, 1, points - 1}], r] /. h -> solfunc[t, r] /. t -> 10], {r, lb, rb}]`...

Comment: @lxy Suppose I want to calculate $\sin(\pi/2)$, what's wrong with the following code?: 
 `f[Pi/2] /. f -> Sin[x]`

Comment: @xzczd we should use `f[Pi/2]/. f -> Sin`, changing the function only

Comment: @lxy Then what's wrong with `h[lb][t] /. h -> solfunc[10, r]`?

Comment: @xzczd, for this example, using `Plot[h[r, t] /. h -> solfunc /. t -> 10 // Evaluate, {r, lb, rb}]` should be correct? But I cannot figure out how to plot `J` at a time

Comment: @lxy How can `h[lb][t] + h[2 lb][t]` be transformed to `solfunc[t, lb] + solfunc[t, 2 lb]`?

Comment: @xzczd, honestly, I cannot figure it out and this might be the heart of the question. I noticed that the orders of the independent variables in `h` and `solfunc` are different. Clearly, `h[lb][t] + h[2 lb][t] /. h -> solfunc` does not work.

Comment: @lxy Then please re-visit the document related to pattern matching carefully.

Comment: @xzczd, I still have difficulty in plotting some defined functions. May I consult the function `P = P[r, t]`? I'm trying `solp[r_, h_] = D[h, r, r] + D[h, r]/r + a^2/h^3; Plot[Evaluate[solp[r, h] /. h[r_][t] -> solfunc[t, r] /. t -> 10], {r, lb, rb}]`, which gives an empty figure again. Sorry if it is a low-level problem.