# N[variable,2] displays 6 digits

Tags: manipulate, precision-and-accuracy, digits

The following code doesn't behave as I expect. Rather than getting 2 digits upon varying r, I get the default value of 6 digits. What's up?

```
Manipulate[ 
 eq = Row[{"(-\[Infinity], ", N[1/r, 2] ")"}];
 Show[Graphics[{Black, Text[eq]}]],
 {{r, 1}, 0.5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Initialization :> (y[t_, r_] := 1/(1 - r t);)]
```

This code is a snippet from a larger Manipulate.

Comment: See also: [(3736)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3736/121),
[(7871)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7871/121),
[(10624)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10624/121)

Comment: I think you want `Round` rather than `N` there. Take a look at [How do you round numbers so that it affects computation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7871/27951) and [A problem about function N](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55292/27951).