# Rounding numbers to certain numbers of significant figures

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, output

I have code which outputs numbers, for example,(0.2945847, 0.8647834, 1.6*10^-6) and similar. I would like to take these numbers and round them to 4 significant figures, but I can't find a way to do this.

I know N[expr, digits] can round an expression to certain significant figures but it doesn't seem to work with my numbers.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7872/363

Comment: If you are looking for a way to print the numbers, then you can use [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html).

Comment: @ChrisDegnen That post is about absolute rounding, not about rounding to a fixed amount of significant digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`N` is implemented such it will never lose precision when the input is already a floating point number (with more significant digits than the second argument of `N`).

In order to enforce rounding to 4 digits, use `SetPrecision`:

```
a = {0.2945847, 0.8647834, 1.6*10^-6};
SetPrecision[a, 4]
```

> {0.2946, 0.8648, 1.600*10^-6}

Answer (score 2):

Below is the function I use for rounding to `p` significant figures. I played around with a few methods, but settled on `MantissaExponent` on the philosophy of using built-in functions whenever possible.

```
NTo[x_?Internal`RealValuedNumericQ, p_Integer?Positive] := 
  Function[{m, e}, N[Round[m 10^p]10^(e - p)]] @@ MantissaExponent[x];

NTo[z_?NumericQ, p_Integer?Positive] := Complex[NTo[Re[z], p], NTo[Im[z], p]];

NTo[p_Integer?Positive][x_] := NTo[x, p];
```

Example usage:

```
NTo[4] /@ {0.2945847, 0.8647834, 1.6*10^-6}

(* {0.2946, 0.8648, 1.6*10^-6} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NsigFig[x_, digits_] := 
 If[x == 0, 0., Round[x, 0. + 10^(Round[Log[10, x] - digits + 0.5])]]
```

Try:

```
NsigFig[3.1415926, 4]
(* 3.142 *)
```